# Per user level synchronization in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am designing an upload functionality with Spring MVC. All uploads from the client reach an endpoint which handles an ajax call. The controller that is mapped to the endpoint calls a function in a "@Service" class.

This function does the actual upload by uploading it to my cloud file system, and modifying a session variable. The problem is that it takes a while for the upload to be completed. Thus, the time for my controller to return prolongs. I want my controller to return right away by starting a thread to handle the upload and then return. If multiple uploads from the same client call the endpoint at the same time, I want to ensure a synchronized access to the session variable, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses servlet technology, different thread is created for each request on a servlet ( not different instances ) so what you really want to accomplish regarding the threads is already done.

Comment: Say two requests come in roughly concurrently, they both try to modify a session attribute. Would that result in some synchronization problems?

Comment: But the two threads race to modify that shared session attribute data, how does that work?

Comment: The container you are running your servlets on will handle this

Comment: Not sure about the documentation , it depends on your container, you can search on how  a container handle different requests on the same servlet (for example tomcat) and you will find many useful articles